Error 500 when adding Gmail to iPhone mail
I’m trying to add my Gmail account to my iPhone running iOS 15.8.3. I have successfully added it to my iPad and iMac email, but I get a 500 error code on the iPhone.
I go to Settings-Mail-Accounts and choose Add Account-Google. I enter my Google email ID and password. It says to check the Google app on my iPad. A message appears there asking if it’s me trying to sign in. I tap yes.
A message appears on the iPhone showing a number, and another message appears on the iPad in the Google app asking again if it’s me trying to sign in. I tap Yes again and it shows me 3 numbers and asks me which one appears on the iPhone. I tap the one that matches. The iPhone then displays a Google message: “500.  That’s an error. There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know.”
This has been happening for over 14 hours. I am able to log into Google via every other avenue I’ve tried on the iPhone and multiple other devices (e.g. Chrome, Gmail app, Google app, Google photos, Google Voice, etc.). I’ve tried shutting down all other apps before trying, and powering the iPhone off and on. I have about 18GB of free storage on the iPhone. Any suggestions?

Should you edit this with details to distinguish it from the linked question,  the community can review this for reopening
