iPhone SE adding Gmail account return 500 error
I have an iphone SE first generation (2017) with last version of OS (15.8.3). I had to delete one of my email accounts because of some problems on the iphone.
When i want to add it again, i can add  my email , then i have to authenticate and google returns me a 500 error each time.
Another person in France has this issue with an iPhone 8.


I tried to

Clear browser cache and cookies (chrome version on iphone)
Disable double authentification in Google security account
Reinstall iphone and restore

I still have a 500 error at authentification ...
I know that 500 error is server side but it seems to come from malformated datas send througth authentification.
How can I deal with this?

Understood. Just offering thoughts on isolating where the failure is temporary or related to the older iOS. Is google offering a support path to you?

Google support works only for entreprise account (paid accounts)

Same issue today with iPhone 8 Pascal Beynel
Are you located in France ?

Yes, I'm in France ;-)

Can you try the Gmail app?

Gmail app is working. But i can't have the calendars and contacts synch with the Gmail app

Since this day (August 18 2024), adding an account is now working.
I have tried to add my account each day thoses previous days, and it was still not working.
The was no IOS update so it must have come from Google services who have been updated to fix this error.

The solution is UPDATE your iOS to 17.6.1 and try add account again.
Since your device may not run this OS, can you borrow a device to test that new iOS registers fine for your account?
Then you can decide to find a new provider service or if your account is temporarily blocked and keep working support to get it fixed. It’s possible Google / Alphabet disabled the account setup process for older devices.

Iphone SE first generation can't update to v16 or v17, but we still got updates for v15.

I have the same issue using an iPhone 8, updated to iOS 16.7.10 (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/474495/error-500-when-adding-gmail-to-iphone-mail). So the answer is not just to update iOS, although that may be a necessary step.

Thanks @DeanGaryet the linked question is missing the information that you updated from 15.8.3 to 16.7.10
